# PHP MySQL Log of Additional Submissions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I have an online Test Taking System where once the user submits the test form it adds a row to the table like so;

Employee ID | Employee Name | Date Test 1 Taken

Employees can retake tests so I want to replace the 'Date Test 1 Taken' with the date of the most recent submission, however, I also want to log all the previous submissions.

So basically I'd want a second table with 3 previous submissions like so;
Employee ID | Previous Submission 1 | Previous Submission 2 | Previous Submission 3

Is it possible to essentially do "This employee retook this test on a different date, so take the current date in 'Date Test 1 Taken', move it to the other table under 'Previous Submission 1' and place the current date in 'Date Test 1 Taken'?  Is it extremely complicated, if at all possible..?

Comment: what yous hould have is a "test_taken_id", so that each testing session has its own id, with its own answer sets. then it doesn't matter how often a person takes the test. each test gets its own record set and can be uniquely identified.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I'm not recording test answers / scores (validated by JS).  All I record is when the test was completed.  And I also need to be able to generate a list of employees and when they took their test but only show the most recent attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a design improvement. It seems your goal is to keep a running record of each employee and test type. Your table should be something like:

```
EmployeeTest table: EmployeeID, EmployeeName, TestNum, DateTaken, Score
```

You insert a row to the EmployeeTest table for every test taken. You can then write queries like:

```
select EmployeeID, EmployeeName, TestNum, DateTaken, Score from EmployeeTest order by DateTaken
```

To see all test for an employee in date order. Or:

```
select EmployeeName, TestNum, max(DateTaken), Score from EmployeeTest where EmployeeID = 'joe' and TestNum = 1
```

To get the latest date and score for employee 'joe' for test #1

Of course the EmployeeName should be broken out into an Employee table (EmployeeID, EmployeeName), but I didn't want to muddy the issue with joins at this point.

Have fun...

Comment: The overall plan is to generate a list of all the employees who have taken the test, but I only want it to show the most recent attempt.  That involves doing a foreach loop to echo everything into a table, but in your select statement you use ORDER BY to only show the latest result for that employee..  Would I still be able to foreach all the results into a giant table while only displaying the most recent submissions per employee?  Does that make sense?

Comment: In that case, you would use a query like the second one without selecting an employee and add a GROUP BY. That will return the latest entry for each employee for the selected test. Like this: `select EmployeeName, TestNum, max(DateTaken), Score from EmployeeTest where TestNum = 1 group by EmployeeID`  Then you can loop through the results as you describe.